# Unwanted generation of namespace prefix using tHMap after 7.2.1 upgrade

Tags: xml, namespaces, talend

Since the Talend upgrade to version 7.2.1 i'm experiencing some issues with the xml namespace, more precisely:

I'm having a job that generates xml's using a tHMap component based on a predefined schema and a namespace associated with that schema.
In the namespace configuration i have a `URL="https://www.w3schools.com/"` and the `prefix="default"`. Since Talend Open Studio 7.2.1 that "default" prefix of the namespace is getting generated in the xml like this:

```
<default:Store xmlns:default="https://www.w3schools.com/">
<default:BooksCollection>
    <default:Book>
        <default:Author>
            <default:Name>Some name</default:Name>
            <default:Country xmlns:default="https://www.w3schools.com/">
                <default:Code>GB</default:Code>
            </default:Country>
        </default:Author>
        <default:Genre xmlns:default="https://www.w3schools.com/">Adventure</default:Genre>
        <default:Pages xmlns:default="https://www.w3schools.com/">200</default:Pages>
        <default:Language xmlns:default="https://www.w3schools.com/">English</default:Language>
    </default:Book>
</default:BooksCollection>
```

I tried to remove the prefix from the namespace configuration but i couldn't save the configuration because it couldn't be saved without a prefix.
One more thing related to this issue is that the attribute xmlns should be present only on the first element but it got generated on a "random" number of elements.

Here is my namespace configuration:

```
Prefix = Default
URI = https://www.w3schools.com/
```